# Is pecl still relevant for php

Tags: php, php-extension, pecl

I'm trying to compile php with some specific extensions, and I've come across the pecl project which is supposed to list all the extensions used with php. But the project's website seems to be dead.

- the links I found in another tutorial to download the packages isn't working
- the search feature isn't working
- the ability to add extensions isn't working

So for those who know more about pecl, is it still alive? Did a better replacement come out that I should use instead?

Edit:
Also, if I go the cumbersome route of browsing the package categories one by one to find the package I'm looking for, some categories give me database errors like this. Is the project still being maintained at all? Is there a better replacement?

> ERROR:
>        DB Error: syntax error... SELECT p.id, p.name, p.summary, p.license, p.unmaintained, p.newpk_id, (SELECT COUNT(package) FROM
>   releases WHERE package = p.id) AS numreleases, (SELECT state FROM
>   releases WHERE package = p.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS status,
>   (SELECT version FROM releases WHERE package = p.id ORDER BY id DESC
>   LIMIT 1) AS version, (SELECT releasedate FROM releases WHERE package =
>   p.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS releasedate FROM packages p WHERE
>   category= [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 9]

Comment: It's a community site. If you run over a problem, please report a bug. Maybe they are currently updating the site and a mirror has a problem or such. Please read the about page first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Website works fine for me.

~Cyrix

Comment: Are you able to search for packages. When I do a search, it gives me a blank page!

Comment: Yes, search for json for example http://pecl.php.net/package-search.php?pkg_name=json&bool=AND&submit=Search brings up search options, a filter for date of release, and then one result at the bottom that links to http://pecl.php.net/package/json

Comment: Check my edit. I'm also getting database errors when I try to browse the package categories. In a maintained project, I'd be able to search for the project and find it and download it, which is why I'm asking if this project is being maintained, or if there's a replacement?

Comment: Thanks Ian, it seems there's 2 subdomains, pecl and pecl2. For some reason I was directed to pecl2 and that's what's not working. pecl.php.net is working fine though.

Comment: Seems there has been DB connection issues in the past, judging by [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590888/is-there-any-pecl-mirror)

Answer (score 3):

PECL is totally still relevant to PHP, but I prefer to browse PECL extensions from PHP Docs directly. In this link you will find the officially supported PECL extensions 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php. How to install PECL extension can be found in http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

For other extensions not appear in the Manual they may not be updated or not supported. If you still need more functionality you can check PEAR http://pear.php.net/packages.php